# Miss-aligned upper integral limits when using pause in Beamer

Tags: beamer, pause

I am trying to prepare a lecture that uses integrals in beamer. I wanted to use `\pause` to sequentially reveal the integral and especially the limits so I can pause and ask students to provide the right numbers. However, when I used `\pause` inside the limits it miss-aligned the upper limits as in the attached picture.

[image]

Here are the codes that generated the picture:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
%\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]

  Without pause: $\displaystyle P(X < 26) = \int_{-\infty}^{26}f_{X}(x)dx$\vspace{2ex}

  With pause: $\displaystyle P(X < 26) = \int_{\pause-\infty}^{\pause 26}f_{X}(x)dx$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Babis

Comment: If you replace the lower limit by `_{{\pause}-\infty}` the issue does not arise.

Comment: I realized that my proposal causes problems in the normal, i.e. not handout, mode. Then there is first an integral with upper limit 26, then without limits, and finally with all limits. I think you want a different ordering. And I have no idea why this is, nor why you had the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution based on `\uncover`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]

  Without pause: $\displaystyle P(X < 26) =
  \int_{-\infty}^{26}f_{X}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$\vspace{2ex}

  With pause: $\displaystyle P(X < 26) =
  \int_{{\pause}-\infty{\pause}}^{\uncover<+>{26}}f_{X}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]

 Ooops, I forgot this one\pause

 \dots and this one \pause

  Again out integral $\displaystyle P(X < 26) =
  \int_{{\pause}-\infty{\pause}}^{\uncover<+>{26}}f_{X}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It has the advantage that it does not make use of the `\only` command, which needs to be adjusted once one adds stuff with `\pause` s before the integral.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]

\[
P(X < 26) =
\int
  _{\only<1>{\phantom{-\infty}}\only<2->{-\infty}}
  ^{\only<1-2>{\phantom{26}}\only<3>{26}}f_{X}(x)\,dx
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but if @Babis decides later to add some other stuff with additional `\pause` commands above this bit of code, (s)he would to increase the arguments of `\only` by hand. Do you know why the problem arises in the first place?

Comment: @egreg This is indeed a nice workaround for the particular example. However, it will break down when I have multiple integrals one after the other or even broken by text with pauses, I will have to keep track all of the ``\pauses`` and adjust the numbers accordingly, right?

Comment: @Babis I'm afraid this is it.